# adjust the height of row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file. I want the program when I type in field A1 number "1" to adjust the height of row "1" to a height distinct from the rest of the rows. When I write in field A1 number "2", the height of row "2" should be adjusted to a height distinct from the rest of the rows, and when I write in field A1 number "3", the height of row "3" should be modified to a height distinct from the rest of the rows. And so on . Thank you

Comment: What height value is distinct from other rows?

Answer (score 0):

### Adjust Row Height

- Copy the code into the appropriate modules.
- It is automated, no need to run anything.
- You can copy the sheet module code into any number of sheets, and it will run in all of them.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub adjustRowHeight( _
    CellRange As Range, _
    ByVal NewRowHeight As Double, _
    Optional ByVal DefaultRowHeight As Double = 15)
    
    With CellRange
        Dim Curr As Variant
        Curr = CellRange.Value
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Worksheet.Rows.RowHeight = DefaultRowHeight
        If IsNumeric(Curr) Then
            If Curr >= 1 And Curr <= .Worksheet.Rows.Count Then
                If NewRowHeight >= 0 And NewRowHeight < 410 Then
                    .Worksheet.Rows(CLng(Curr)).RowHeight = NewRowHeight
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Target = Range("A1") Then
            adjustRowHeight Target, 30, 15
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```